# Trying to import cURL command to POSTMAN

Tags: curl, postman

I am trying to import a cURL command on POSTMAN

```
curl -X POST https://www.check-plagiarism.com/apis \ -d "key=YOUR_KEY"
```

And after importing, I am receiving this error `Error while importing Curl: Only the URL can be provided without an option preceding it.All other inputs must be specified via options.`

Can anyone know how to make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there's a copy&paste mistake in your curl, just remove the `\`:

```
curl -X POST https://www.check-plagiarism.com/apis -d "key=YOUR_KEY"
```

Comment: Apparently, the backslash (\\) is the culprit...